# Specific horizontal alignment for enumerated items

Tags: indentation, enumerate, itemize, labels

In my document I have such construction.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}



\begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
     \item Item One
     \begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
         \item Item Two
         \begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
         \item Item Three
         \end{enumerate}
     \end{enumerate}
     \begin{itemize}[label={--}]
     \item Test One
     \item Test Two
     \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output text will be:

```
1. Item One
    1.1 Item Two
        1.1.1 Item Three
    - Test One
    - Test Two
```

But what I really need is:

```
1.       Item One
1.1      Item Two 
1.1.1    Item Three
       - Test One 
       - Test Two ...
11.11.11 Item One Hundred
```

Can I do something like in some simple or not simple way. 
To summarize, I have enumerated elements for which I would like to allocate space for max 11.11.11 numbers as an (enumerated) input, they all should have the same indentation and itemized elements should behave as two level after some enumerated. I should have some label to set if elements behave as enumerated or as itemized.

For example,

```
1.      Item One
        (a) Sub item One
        (b) Sub Item Two
1.1     Item Two
...     - Test sub item One
        - Test sub item Two
```

Comment: Will your items be several lines long?

Comment: Usually yes, after one Item follow long text with bold, italic or underline text or with some other elements.

Comment: And I suppose all further lines in items have to be aligned with the first one?

Comment: Yes, and below exactly code that does it.

Comment: I tested it, and it does it, but the  labels go into the left margin.

Comment: Yes, isn't it the same as specified ? Or you just need different approach ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33339/discussion-between-dmitriy-chasovskoy-and-bernard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label*={\textbf{\arabic*.}},
  leftmargin=0pt,
  labelwidth={40pt},
  align=left}

\begin{document}



\begin{myenumerate}
     \item Item One
       \begin{myenumerate}
         \item Item Two
         \begin{myenumerate}
         \item Item Three
         \end{myenumerate}
     \end{myenumerate}
     \begin{itemize}[label={--},leftmargin=*]
     \item Test One
     \item Test Two
     \end{itemize}
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Test your code with `showframe`…

Comment: @Bernard: Why? What's the matter? Isn't it aligned properly?

Comment: It's aligned quite properly, but I get the labels in the margin.

Comment: @Bernard: I'll take a look later on -- Thanks!